# As a non-canadian resident can I get a mortgage loan in Canada?

Tags: canada, non-residents

I am willing to buy an apartment in Canada, where I'll be living for 5 years with a student visa (I am swiss).

Can I get a mortgage loan in Canada although I am not Canadian neither a permanent resident? What solution do I have?

---

Note: I asked this same question [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/35238/as-a-non-canadian-resident-can-i-get-a-mortgage-loan-in-canada) on money.SE

Comment: If you're on a student visa, how are you going to be earning money to pay the mortgage back?

Comment: @Gagravarr That is definitely another discussion but I appreciate the warning, thks. I can deal with this issue, don't worry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irrespective of where the money for this mortgage will come from (that's bank's risk) there are programs available for non-residents and new residents that have not yet established credit history in Canada.  You will need to go to the banks to find out about details of the programs but here is some basic information from banks:

- [CIBC](https://www.cibc.com/ca/mortgages/new-nonres-homeowner-pgrms.html)
- [TD Q&A](http://www.td.com/to-our-customers/tdhelps/#psce%7Ccid=871%7Clid=1%7Ctid=001%7Cvid=d02526b11)
- [Scotia Bank](http://www.scotiabank.com/ca/en/0,,225,00.html)

Personally if your stay in Canada is limited to 5 years only I would not bother buying a place to live.

Comment: Thanks. The only contact I (not me directly actually) had so far was with HSBC and they didn't seem to offer the possibility for a non-resident to get a mortgage loan. Do you know whether HSBC have such programs for non-residents?